# jQuery listener on File upload button, when any file selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to attach a function to my File upload button, when any file selected.

Now, I use the following code:

```
jQuery("input:file").change(function () {
    console.log("function");
});
```

This is OK, when the user selects the first file, or when she change it to an another file. But I'd like to run the script, when the user selects a file, and after that they open the dialog again, and select the same file second time.

What would be the correct jQuery event?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think this is impossible with a simple HTML file input. You could, however, remove the file input and add in a new one after each selection to reset it and ensure it's fired after each selection.

Comment: Just clean the input. I think then it will always fire. $(this).val(""); inside event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the .on selector...

```
$(document).on('change','#inputFile' , function(){ 
  console.log("function");
});
```

Please check you input in the .on selector and after successfully running the function or even after a fail clean the input

```
$('#inputFile').val("");
```

Comment: I think the `.on('change', ...)` is a shortcut for `.change()`. Or you would attach it to do the `document`, not to the `input`? If I clean the `input`'s `val`, will it upload the file, or I should create a wrapper input for it?

Comment: `.on('change', ...)` is not the same as `.change()` .. it is a shortcut.. ideed but in this context it works different
With this code i create a listener on the `document` which is binded to the `input` ...

I meant you should clean the `input`'s `val` after you uploaded the file... of course with a check if the file is uploaded correctly or some informations missing

Comment: Yep, but I do not want to upload the files async. I want to upload them with the form, as a regular, simple Http site. It's a picture uploader, where the user can choose a picture, then in a jQuery dialog they'll select an area on it. And I'll crop the image to the selected area on the server-side. It works well, when the user chooses an image. It also working, when they choose an other image after the first one, 'cause they changed them mind. But if they want to select an other area, they'll choose the same file in the OS' file-selector dialog, and I want to show them my cropping dialog.

Answer (score 0):

**Minimalist**

```js
$("#myID").change(() => alert('It works!'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="myID">
```

**Also**

```js
$("#myID").change(function(e){
  alert('It works!')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="myID">
```